# How to modify the add node forms using hook_form_alter

Tags: theming, nodes, forms

This is the `$form_id` of a content type: `q_a_node_form`. I'm trying to change its `add/content` form (the title field) using `hook_form_alter`. this is my code in `template.php`:

```
function MYTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
switch ($form_id){
    case "q_a_node_form":
        $form['edit-title']['#size'] = 10;          
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm sure that the case option happens, I already print something in it and it works. why it doesn't work?

Comment: Make sure you use debugging tools to inspect what's actually in the `$form` array before you start trying to change things in it. The CSS ids/classes from the front end are never guaranteed to be anything like the array keys used in the form build.

Comment: yes @Clive you are right. I was looking at its `id` in the html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below code which works.. Form element is **title** instead of **edit-title**.. print $form array to investigate form elements...

```
function MYTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
switch ($form_id){
    case "q_a_node_form":
        $form['title']['#size'] = 10;          
        break;
    }
}
```

If you have installed devel module you can see elements using below code

```
dpm($form);
```